# Create 2d linear list in matlab

Tags: matlab

Very Simple Question that i couldn't find easily on the web so i thought i would ask here:

You can make a 1D linear array like this:

```
1:10 = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1:2:10 = 1 3 5 7 9
```

How can you easily initialise a 2D array ie.

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

and also the same thing but for columns:

```
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
```

Should be a command to do it in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively i have learned that you can use meshgrid:

```
meshgrid(1:4, 1:4) =>

 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
```

Thanks for the help and upvotes.

Comment: Instead of `meshgrid`, I prefer `ndgrid` - it makes a lot more sense to me to first run the index along rows, then columns

Comment: @Jonas are you sure ngrid does what you think it does, ngrid(1:4, 1:4) for me returns a single column of seemingly random values.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It should work the same for you as well, if you spell it `ndgrid`. :)

Comment: @Jonas Nice, hahaha i didn't realise.

Answer (score 2):

```
v = 1:5;
A = repmat(v, 4, 1);
B = repmat(v', 1, 4);
```

`A` and `B` will have what you need.

Another option is to use MATLAB indexing as follows:

```
v = 1:5;
A = v(ones(4, 1), :);
v = [1:5]';
B = v(:, ones(1, 4));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i decided to go with meshgrid, it seemed easier.